# Index of minimum element of matrix

Tags: matlab

How can I find the `(i, j)` index of the minimum element of a matrix?

For example:

```
M = [3 6 2; 5 5 9; 1 4 4];
```

I would want to get the output `(3, 1)`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
M = [3 6 2; 5 5 9; 1 4 4];
[~, ind] = min(M(:));
[i, j] = ind2sub(size(M), ind);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[r,c]=find(M==min(M(:)))
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Could possibly run into issues comparing floats here.

Comment: @excaza I don't see why that would be a problem, `min` doesn't perform any calculations so it should return an exact match

Comment: @excaza - There should be no floating point compare issues.  First you are retrieving the minimum floating point value from this array, then you're comparing **this exact** value that was extracted from this array to all of the other points in this array. This would only be an issue if you extracted a minimum, then performed some calculations on the matrix, and then tried to do a compare..... and I just basically regurgitated what Dan said, but I just wanted to put my two cents in.

Answer (score -1):

```
[value,index] = min(M(:))
```

will give:

```
value = 1
index = 3
```

Comment: This is not what was asked, you could call `sub2ind` on your `index` value to get the correct answer though but this is a linear index when the OP asks for a subscript index

Comment: Oh damn you're right sorry about that I misread the question.